# variance of a recursive distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have the following recursive equation,

$\tilde{S}(k+1) = \beta \bar{r}(k) + (1-\beta)\tilde{S}(k)$

where $\bar{r}(k) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$.

How can I calculate the variance of $\tilde{S}(k)$? (about its mean I think it should be zero).

[I know the answer is $\tilde{S}(k) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \beta\frac{1-(1-\beta)^{2k}}{2-\beta}I)$ but don't know how to reach it.]

Comment: The question can't be answered without knowing the joint distribution of $\tilde S$ and $bar r$. Perhaps you forgot to state the assumption that they're independent?

Comment: @joriki So if we assume that they are independent, how can we solve it?

Comment: Is there an initial condition, e.g. the distribution of $\tilde S(0)$?

Comment: @Math1000 I don't actually have any but we can assume one if you think that's simplifies the problem.